# mat-checkbox custom color cannot be changed

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material for my project and I want to change color of mat-checkbox, but don't want to use theming, so obviusly I used Elements and Styles sections in my Chrome Browser and traced classes which mat-checkbox uses and found this: ".mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element".

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
  background-color: black!important;
}
```

So, this is my code, I tried ::ng-deep, /deep/ and without any of those, and result is always the same, checkbox color is not changed, but in "Styles" I can clearly see that it says that I have overwritten its color.

[image]

[image]

Here are versions of things I use:

```
"@angular/animations": "^7.1.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
```

How can I change color?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ripple` is the name of the water drop ripple effect that is displayed when you click on Material components, so you're targeting the wrong element.

Use:

```
// overwrite the checkbox background
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background, 
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: black !important;
}

// overwrite the ripple overlay on hover and click
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox:not(.mat-checkbox-disabled) .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

If you want to change the color globally it's better to use [theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

Comment: You are right. I traced wrong element, and when looking into "Styles", I thought I changed color, because background and ripple have same color. But your example for background didn't work, this worked for me in the end: .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background. Thank you for your answer, it guided me towards solution.

Comment: @AleksaMilosevic The css selector you posted in your comment is the exact same one I used in my answer.

Comment: u are right, it seems that your answer didn't work for me bacause there is no !important. Sorry for mistake. Your answer is solution to my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, glad I could help. I'll add the `!important` to my answer just to be sure, though in the tests I've made it worked for me without the `important`.

Answer (score 4):

Use global scss in styles.scss and that should work.

```
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for me above answers did not work for indeterminate state while overriding styles in a table, but the below code did

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-indeterminate,
.mat-checkbox-checked {
    &.mat-primary .mat-checkbox-background {
        background-color: $ your-color !important;
    }
    &.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
        background-color: $ your-color !important;
    }
    &.mat-warn .mat-checkbox-background {
        background-color: $ your-color !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css to `.mat-checkbox-background`

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-primary .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-primary .mat-checkbox-background{
  background: pink!important;
}
```

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-lttxve?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.css)

Comment: It is same result, in "Styles" it says that color is changed, but it is not. Look at images, it is exactly same result.

Comment: do you see my example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-lttxve?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.css

Comment: It is still same result, because @angular/core and @angular/material versions in your example and my project differ greatly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parent selector as per your requirements:

```
.mat-checkbox-background {
      border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      background-color: transparent;
    
    }
    .mat-checkbox-checked {
      .mat-checkbox-checkmark {
        background: #ffffff;
        .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
          stroke: #2baf35;
          stroke-width: 5px;
        }
      }
    }
```

Output:[image]